# Delphi IdMappedPortTCP Question

Tags: delphi, indy

Is there a way to disconnect an active connection? I know with OnConnect you can reject connections...but thats only when there connecting

Comment: I have sort of found a way to do this kinda ghettoish using OnOutboundData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the TidMappedPortTCP is a TidTCPServer descendant, so you can basically use a few different approaches to disconnect active clients. For example, if you want to disconnect an active client inside the OnExecute event (based on some arbitrary criteria) you can simply do this somewhere inside the event handler:

```
AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
```

If you need to disconnect an active connection somewhere else in your code (eg. not in the OnExecute event handler), the approach would be something like this:

- Create a list (TList or some collection class) which will hold your active connections;
- Inside OnConnect event handler, add any new clients to this list;
- Inside OnDisconnect event handler, remove disconnected clients from this list;

This way you will always have a collection of active clients which will enable you to find a specific client, access it's connection object and call the Disconnect method when needed.

Let me know if you need more detailed code sample.

Comment: You do not need to maintain your own `TList` of connections.  `TIdTCPerver` already provides one of its own - the `Threads` property (Indy 9 and earlier) or the `Contexts` property (Indy 10).